# 'Drop us a line' - letter or phone call?

Tags: phrases

According to [the Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drop+a+line), dropping someone a line means sending them a short message.

Is this correct? I always thought it meant phoning someone, the line referring to a telephone line.

Comment: I find the answers here very interesting because, like @jdln, I had always used this to mean to phone someone. If I ever asked someone to _drop me a line_ I was certainly expecting a call.

Comment: To *get someone on the line* means to establish a telephone connection, and you can say *the line dropped* if that connection is lost involuntarily, but I've never heard *drop a line* used to mean *contact by telephone*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When used as "drop _me_ a line", think of the "line" being drop/tossed in the direction of the person.

Comment: I can imagine how OP and Andy came to their understanding of the usage - I'm just saying I've never come across it before. Nor have the three people who've posted answers, apparently.

Comment: Sites like [this one](http://www.cornerstone-builders.co.uk/?p=51) and [this one](http://www.accessnorth.co.uk/#/contact-us/4551436202) show that's it's not unheard of. These are both from the first page of Google results for the phrase "drop us a line". I wonder if the confusion lies somewhere between a _line_ of text and a telephone _line_.

Comment: Also - it might be worth pointing out: if this is an issue of ambiguity and you want to make sure someone calls you on the phone, the phrase "give me/us a bell" is used exclusively for phone calls. [The free online dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+a+bell) notes this as British and Australian usage.

Comment: 'Drop a line' is defined as "a few words in writing" (1647) but perhaps you are confused with 'drop a dime' which is a telephone call

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It refers to a line of text in a letter, so it means sending a short message (maybe with just one single line of text).

(If you drop the line during a phone call, that means you're hanging up)

Answer (score 7):

History says the telephone was invented in 1876.  I imagine A. G. Bell would be amazed at this Ngram (could he see it) if, indeed, it refers to telephone communication!
[image: ngram]

Comment: +1. But, what does it mean NOW?

Answer (score 6):

**Drop me a line** invites someone to write something to you: a message, a note or a short letter. It probably has to do with the lines that comprise a piece of writing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the line in "Hold the line" with the line in "a line of text". The statement you posted has the second meaning.

Answer (score 0):

"Drop a line" also means to *install* a phone line, and the meaning has portmanteau'd into "give me a call" in many circles. This I can verify from first-hand experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion here is in the meaning behind 'a short message' in freedictionary.com.

A 'message' in this case does not necessarily mean a *text* message.  It can just as easily mean a phone message, and is very frequently used to mean just that.

Answer (score -1):

It's funny how many phrases in language completely lose context with their origins over time. "Drop a call" seems like a different nuance than "drop a line". And there is the action of dropping a line as in the actual telephone cable line being dropped into the ground for installation.

I also interpret "drop me a line" to come from dropping someone a line of rope to reach them (connect with them). By that interpretation, and mode of communication involving any kind of line seems to qualify – a telephone line, a line of text, or even a pickup line in a bar (which has the added irony of dropping vs. picking up) :)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and your submission does not attempt to answer the original question. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange/help) for guidance.