# Use of "Drop me a line"

Tags: expressions, idioms

One person with whom I've emailed before said to "drop me [them] a line". I always thought the intention of this phrase is to call the person, specifically by phone (via telephone line). It seems this person means to email them. I do think it's possible they mean to call them. Is it a widely accepted use of this phrase to mean "contact me" in general? Is this usage common among certain groups of people? Am I wrong in associating this with phones in particular?

Comment: Originally *a line* meant a line of written text that you'd *drop* in a mailbox.  It very well could be used more generally today to mean contact me, but email seems a more likely medium than telephone- IF they wanted you to call, they'd have said, "Call me sometime."

Comment: "Is it a widely accepted use of this phrase to mean 'contact me' in general?"  Yes.

Answer (score 5):

In the U.S., I think I'm safe in stating that, in the vast majority of cases, 'drop me a line' implies written communication, and never implies calling via telephone or any other means. Before the Internet was invented, 'drop me a line' always meant 'write me a note/postcard/letter'. Nowadays, the phrase could also imply emailing.

I can't speak for British English, or for speakers from other parts of the world.

Edit:
I also just discovered that this is a duplicate:
['Drop us a line' - letter or phone call?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49035/drop-us-a-line-letter-or-phone-call/49037#49037)